# how to insert pictures on an Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel file that contains a bunch of Students' informations .
i inserted a column 'Barcode'.
I generated for each student a QRcode and put them in an array .
I want to generate pictures of these QRCodes and then insert them into my Excel File .I tried with qr.png('NameOfTheStudent') but the cells stay empty .
How can i do that ?

Here is my code :

```
import uuid 
import pandas as pd
import pyqrcode 


def generateBarCode(length):
    return str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')[0:length]

df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('Komplette
GastAccountFHZugangsdatenFertig.xlsx'))
array=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    qr=pyqrcode.create(generateBarCode(8))
    array.append(qr.png(df['Name'][i]))

df.insert(8,'Barcode',array)


with pd.ExcelWriter('Komplette-GastAccountFHZugangsdatenFertig.xlsx') as 
writer :
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

sorry i can't share the excel file , it contains confidential informations .
thank you

Comment: Don’t think you can do this. Try doing it in Excel manually - when you paste an image it hovers over the cells rather than going into a cell. You might be able to put a link to a picture into a cell. Good luck.

Comment: I agree with the above, it might be best to create a folder of images here and then even just use a vba script to import them. There are several posts here on importing images to Excels using vba.